# Parsing json difficulties

Tags: json, api, android-studio, parsing

Hello I've been working on a recipes app, I have everything working I get no error but on the actual parse function. I could really appreciate it if you gave me some tips because I'm new at this and I learned from a much simpler api link and this one is more difficult to parse and I'm confused of what to do.

This is the link I'm trying to parse:
https://api.edamam.com/search?q=recipe&app_id=fd6b284e&app_key=d7f2b601ed78fb706f422c0bb83eeb6b

and this is the code. basically during the loop I get an error at "image" it says it can't find it. It took me time to understand why because only recipe is an element of the array "hits", but "recipe" is also an object that contains more objects inside of it and I'm curious if there's a way to do another loop for recipes but I don't know how to do it because it's an object and not an actual array? I'm trying to display the image, the recipe's name and the ingredients in a recyclerviewer. And I assume the only reason it doesn't display anything is because I'm doing the parsing wrong. I tried putting a background on the actual RV and the background is showing up once I start it so I'm only assuming that could be the actual problem. (the wrong parsing)

```
  private void parseJSON()
    {
        String url = "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=recipe&app_id=fd6b284e&app_key=d7f2b601ed78fb706f422c0bb83eeb6b";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");
                            for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String recipeName = hit.getString("recipe");
                                String imageURL = hit.getString("image");
                                String ingredients = hit.getString("ingredients");

                                mMeals.add(new Meals(imageURL, recipeName, ingredients));

                            }

                            mMealAdapter = new MealAdapter(HomeActivity.this, mMeals);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMealAdapter);
                            mMealAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`recipe` is not a string, It is an object. You should call `getJSONObject('recipe')` and find `image` inside this `jsonobject`.

```
JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject recipeObject = hit.getJSONObject("recipe");
String imageURL = recipeObject.getString("image");
String recipeName = hit.getString("label");
```

I think `recipeName` is `label` inside `recipeObject`.

`ingredients` is also not a string, It is a `JSONObject`, get this by using `getJSONObject('ingredients')`